# Magento 2.1.9 upgrade to 2.2.0 - Error on setup:upgrade with Magento_Sales table

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, composer, zend-framework, magento-upgrade

Upgrading magento from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 and during the automatic `bin/magento setup:upgrade` process it runs all upgrades fine until it reaches the `magento_sales` table where it produces this error.

There are around another 500 id's within the error but I have removed them for the purpose of keeping the post short.

I had migrated sales, customer, product data from our Magento Enterprise existing live site to magento 2.1 but not had this issue when doing subsequent updates.

Module `Magento_Widget`:

Module `Magento_Sales`:

> Upgrading data.. Error converting field `product_options` in table `sales_order_item` where `item_id`= 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 13, 17, 21, 26, 43, 46, 48, 69, 70, 71, 76, 81, 82, 91, 98, 101, 105, 108, 111, 116, 117, 122, 123, 127, 131, 135, 139, 141, 144, 145, 154, 164, 166, 171, 172, 173, 7659, 7660, 7671, 7672, 7681 using Magento\Sales\Setup\SerializedDataConverter.
>   Fix data or replace with a valid value.

Failure reason: '**Unable to unserialize value.**'

Any information on how to resolve would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue:

```
Error converting field `info` in table `magento_logging_event` where `log_id`=3 using Magento\Logging\Setup\ObjectConverter.
```

Turned out that a long serialized value in `magento_logging_event` was truncated and could not be unserialized. Deleting the row in question solved the problem. **Of course, deleting rows with errors is acceptable for logs but not for sales tables!**

Comment: I just had the same. I deleted the cell value. Strange though - it didn't happen locally.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the field contents to NULL solved my issue.

```
UPDATE `sales_order_item` SET `product_options` = NULL WHERE `product_options` = '';

UPDATE `sales_order_payment` SET `additional_information` = NULL WHERE `additional_information` = '';

UPDATE `sales_payment_transaction` SET `additional_information` = NULL WHERE `additional_information` = '';

UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET `additional_data` = NULL WHERE `additional_data` = '';
```

Comment: updating NULL is not the solution to problem, Their are some information missing for order in this case. Like for me shipping information is not available for imported orders.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the field contents to NULL solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `product_options` column in the table `sales_order_item` should store valid serialized object as a string. This error means that some of values invalid. To resolve this issue select all values specified in the error message and check them using php:

```
unserialize($value);
```

where in the `$value` one of the values in which setup script detect error. This way you can get error like this:

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 14 of 33 bytes

Then just check you string, correct it and insert manually in the row from where it was taken (see ids in error message).

You can get more info about serialization [here (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) or [here](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/serialization.html)

**PS:** setup script converts serialized values to the JSON type since Magento version 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any luck with this? The commonality I've noticed is on the item ids listed, the product_options field is blank.

Comment: Hey, sadly no luck with fixing this yet

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with field metadata containing '' instead NULL
To identify fields with issue:
SELECT * FROM url_rewrite
 where metadata=''
;

and to change value '' with NULL use:
UPDATE `url_rewrite` SET `metadata`=NULL WHERE `metadata`='';

If multiple schemas include your schema name
UPDATE `something`.`url_rewrite`

Comment: Please test on dev server first

Comment: @stephenrwc i have also same error . Can you  please tell me how you solve this error .

Comment: hey @Rahulocodewire 11  - In the end I tried these options but after further investigation it looked as it the sales data was actually corrupt in the original transfer so I dropped the sales tables and re-imported the data into magento 2.2.0 which resolved the issue... hope that helps!

Comment: Great Thanks for the reply  I will try and let see what happen

Comment: Are you delete only sales_order_item table or all sales table ?